# Marmalade C++ Testing on iPhone 5 (iOS 7.1.2): Can`t get past splash screen in debug

Tags: c++, iphone, ios7, marmalade, marmalade-iwui

so I have been working with Marmalade for a while now, and have now gone to testing. On android so far, I tested two example applications included in the SDK, called IwNUIBasicApplication, and IwNUIKitchenSink. I also tested a third simple self-written UI-heavy app. All three run nicely on my android phone.

Now, I want to test on my iPhone, so I followed the steps at http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/iOS+setup+guide

and

http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/Deploying+to+and+testing+on+iOS+devices

to get certificates, set up provisioning profiles, etc, and finally build the app using Marmalade Hub, having settings:

platform: iOS configuration: iphone (default) build: GCC ARM Debug

This is the build output:

> Current Build: GCC ARM Debug (Fri Aug 22 16:16:17 2014) Please set up all development dependencies before deploying. Go to the Dependency Checker (More.../Dependency Checker) to set. Not all deployment dependencies are set, these are needed before submitting to a store.
>
> Calling mkb to build: C:/Marmalade/7.3/examples\IwNUI\IwNUIKitchenSink\IwNUIKitchenSink.mkb Calling mkb to build completed

Then, I click Packagae & Install, and get this output:

> Current Build: GCC ARM Debug (Fri Aug 22 16:16:17 2014) Please set up all development dependencies before deploying. Go to the Dependency Checker (More.../Dependency Checker) to set. Not all deployment dependencies are set, these are needed before submitting to a store.
>
> Deploying: iphone WARNING: No valid iOS launch images were specified.
> There will be no launch image displayed at runtime.
>
> WARNING: No provisioning profile set for iOS development build - push
> notifications and email will not work SUCCESS (WITH WARNINGS): Package
> written to'C:\Marmalade\7.3\examples\IwNUI\IwNUIKitchenSink\build_iwnuikitchensink_vc12x\deployments\default\iphone\debug'
> [took 8.14s]
>
> ERROR: Error running ideviceinstaller.exe (-1073741515)

I don`t think the warnings should be a problem, and the error, I am not quite sure about, but, I then continue to install the app to my phone by dragging the generated .ipa file into the iPhone COnfiguration Utility and installing it on my phone.

So, the app is now on my phone, and when I tap it to run it, I get the debug screen at the beginning, just as in android, then the add for the game signal to the stars (free license), and then the "made with Marmalade" splashscreen. However, unlike on my android, where then the actual app is loaded, and I can see all the different UI elements, on my iPhone, the app just stays in this made with marmalade splashscreen, and I have no idea why.

Does anyone have any input on this, why this is happening, and it doesn't actually procees into the actual app? This happens with IwNUIBasicApplication, IwNUIKitchenSink, and a third app I wrote myself. All three work on my android, but on iPhone, they get stuck in the splash screen.

The phone itself, however, stays responsive, its just the app that doesn't continue anywhere. The phone is an iPhone 5 running iOS 7.1.2.

Thanks for any and all help!

Cheers,

Chris

Update: So, I just tried the same thing again, just, this time, building it in release version, not debug, and now it runs on my iphone as well. Not sure why. Anyone any input, why it runs in release, but not in debug on my iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:
Provisioning profile IS hard requirement for deploying on iOS:

"WARNING: No provisioning profile set for iOS development build"
development = debug and distribution = releas